# Date dimension for parallel dates

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, database-schema, universe

I have a schema to show sales amount by customer and by date. A requirement is to be able to show the sales amount for each customer for the same date the previous quarter (so 21/08/2015 - 21/05/2015). I have added a ParallelQuarterDate column in my date dimension using DATEADD(qq,-1,FullDate).

To be able to fulfill the requirement, I have created an alias of the fact table which joins on the ParallelQuarterDate field in the Date dimension with the normal fact table joining on the normal DateKey field in the Date dimension. Both fact tables join on the customer dimension as well to be able to report by Customer.

It all works perfectly apart from when I try to aggregate the sales amount by month and that is because of the different number of days in each month. So in the date dimension, against the date 31/12/2015 there is a ParallelQuarterDate of 30/09/2015 and against 30/12/2015 it's 30/09/2015 again so it's double counting. Obviously, you get the opposite effect with dates like 30/06/2015 which then has a ParallelQuarterDate of 30/03/2015 bypassing the fact that March has a 31st day as well.

[image]

What would the best way be to achieve the correct aggregation by month? I'm thinking of creating a date table with a month granularity and then join the aliased fact table to both date dimensions and the Customer dimension.

Please let me know your thoughts. Thanks!

Comment: What 'tool' are you using to aggregate? If you write a SQL query this isn't a problem. What tool are you using that aggregates this incorrectly?

Comment: Well, it's SQL. But because the lowest grain of the date table is date and not month and I'm using a DATEADD to calculate the parallel dates then you end up with scenarios where, for instance, the date 30/09/2014 will be repeated twice - once against 30/12/2014 and once for 31/12/2014. The problem doesn't come from the aggregation but from the way the dateadd works and how the parallel dates are originally calculated.

Comment: Ah now I understand. This is where you need to get 'the business' to come up with a model that allows you to perform the analysis required. For example it might be important that the exact weekday is matched (i.e Saturday and Saturday) in which case you should use day-365 and roll up to a quarter. Is there anything about the original requirement that helps you make a design decision?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the values are only valid when you aggregate up to the month level, so I would run an aggregate query for month N, and then another aggregate query for month N-3. Joining days across quarters (or months, or even years) is not valid.